# Somar minutos em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo algo para cálculo de soma de horas e minutos, e não vejo solução.

Preciso receber um horário colado formatado assim `09:00`, mas com hora aleatória em um `input` e clicando em submit alterar o html com a hora do input com adição de 70 minutos. Não consegui passar dessa parte e ainda nem tentei somar os minutos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa missão?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<span> hora inicio </span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function hora1(){
    var horas = getElementById("hrs")
    var hr1 = horas.split(":");    // a hora sera colada com ":" no input, entao preciso dar um split, separar minutos de hora e somar 70 minutos. 
    var hr2 = hr1[0]+":"+hr1[1]; // ainda preciso somar os minutos e mostrar na exibição final com os 70 minutos a mais dessa hora do input
 m.innerHTML = hr2;
} 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="m">
  09:50
</div>
<input type="text" id="hrs">
  <button onclick="hora1()">TESTAR</button>
</body>
</html>
```

consegui resultado mas sem a possibilidade de digitar a hora, o que não é o que eu precisava

```
<!--          EM JAVASCRIPT EM UM ARQUIVO PHP COM RESULTADO OK MAS RECEBENDO A HORA DO SISTEMA -->
<html>
<body>
<h2>Somar 70 minutos</h2>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var mc = 1; 
var mc5 = 20;
var d1 = new Date(); 
var d2 = new Date();
d1.setHours(+d2.getHours()+(mc) ); 
d1.setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes()+(mc5) ); 
document.write("#resultado: " + " " + d1.getHours()+":"+d1.getMinutes());
</script>
</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: O que seria horá aleatória ??

Comment: EXEMPLOS:  07:53  ou  20:35

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o objeto Date do JavaScript. Primeiro você deve converter o horário recebido para um **timestamp**. Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
function toTimestamp(horario){
  var aux = horario.split(':'), dt = new Date();
  dt.setHours(aux[0]);
  dt.setMinutes(aux[1]);
  dt.setSeconds(0);
  return dt.getTime();
}
```

A função acima, recebe um horário e retorna um timestamp. Um timestamp é a data/hora convertida em milissegundos (isso em JavaScript). Sendo assim podemos definir 70 minutos com um timestamp também, basta converter para milissegundos.

```
var minutosAdd = 70*60*1000; // 70 minutos em milissegundos
```

Agora que se tem o timestamp da hora passada e o timestamp de 70 minutos, basta somá-los. Podemos ter a função **mais70minutos()** que recebe uma string com o horário e devolve uma outra string com o horário passado somado com os 70 minutos.

```
function mais70minutos(hora){
  var timeHoraFinal = toTimestamp(hora) + minutosAdd;
  var dt = new Date(timeHoraFinal);
  var horaRetorno = (dt.getHours() < 10) ? '0'+dt.getHours() : dt.getHours();
  horaRetorno += (dt.getMinutes() < 10) ? '0'+dt.getMinutes(): dt.getMinutes();
  return horaRetorno;
 }
```

Usando essas funções da forma que achar melhor é possível que seu problema seja revolvido. Espero ter ajudado. Dê uma conferida em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2):

Use o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) para facilitar seu trabalho.

Veja um exemplo:

```
 var hora = documento.getElementById('hrs');

 var resultado = moment(hora, 'hh:mm').add(70, 'minutes').format('hh:mm')
```

Se as horas do `input` forem `11:30`, o resultado será `12:40`.

**Explicando o código**

O segundo parâmetro da função `moment` recebe o formato de entrada da data. A função `add` adiciona uma quantidade de tempo, e o segundo parâmetro informa o tipo (no caso poderia ser `hours`, `month`, `years` e afins), mas precisamos usar `minutes`. E for fim, o `format` permite colocar a saída no formato necessário.

[Documentação do MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

onde errei? 
nao deu certo, retorna invalid date:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="moment.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Somar 70 minutos</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fff(){
 var hora = document.getElementById('hrs');
 var resultado = moment(hora, 'hh:mm').add(70, 'minutes').format('hh:mm');
    document.getElementById("hrs2").innerHTML = resultado;
}
</script>
<p id="hrs2"></p>
<input type="text" id="hrs">
  <button onclick="fff()">TESTAR</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var hora = document.getElementById('hrs').value;

Comment: var hora = document.getElementById('hrs').value;